# Invalid Credentials Error when updating file to Google drive API

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, drive

I have been trying to replace files using google API only with the Python HTTPS module. Can somebody please help me with how I can replace the file only with an HTTPS module?

```
import sys
import json
import requests
import sys

Acesstoken = ""

params = {
        "grant_type": "refresh_token",
        "client_id": "xxx",
        "client_secret": "xxxx",
        "refresh_token": "xxxx"
        }

authorization_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token"


r = requests.post(authorization_url, data=params)

if r.ok:
    token = str((r.json()['access_token']))
    Refreshtoken = Acesstoken + token
else:
    print('Failed')
    sys.exit()



headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + str(Acesstoken),
    }


metadataF= {
    'name': "Test",
    'parents':["1vXn346cBsarvkPthqtI1OLzsMzeQQlBX"]
}

files = {
    'data':('metadata', json.dumps(metadataF), 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'), 
    'file': open("./credentials.json", "rb"),
    }



r2= requests.post(
    "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/XXXXXXXX?uploadType=multipart",
    headers= headers,
    files= files
)

print(r2)
```

I only want to use Python's Https Module only. I don't want to use google client library. Please help me if this is possible.

Error

> <Response [401]> with this ` { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "authError", "message": "Invalid Credentials", "locationType": "header", "location": "Authorization" } ], "code": 401, "message": "Invalid Credentials" }

[image]

Comment: Do you have an error? whats wrong with what you have now?

Comment: Its saying `<Response [404]>`

Comment: edit your question and post the fulll error message it may help someone in the future.

Comment: I've added the error

Comment: I don't know, you can use the python client libraries to such things less verbose , right ?

Comment: is there any reason you don't want to use the Python lib?

Comment: @AnkitJingala please dont update questions and change them.  I answered your question.  If you have a new issue post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

> <Response [401]> with this ` { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "authError", "message": "Invalid Credentials", "locationType": "header", "location": "Authorization" } ], "code": 401, "message": "Invalid Credentials" }

Invalid Credentials means that your token has expired.  Access tokens are only valid for an hour. Refresh tokens are only valid for seven days if your app is still in testing.

Comment: I did the same as your's but its showing `<Response [404]>`

Comment: not found means the user doesnt have access.  Do a file.list and check that you can see the file.

Comment: But Uploading is still working with that token. I guess there is a problem with the request URL  I guess

Comment: Please check updated

Comment: please dont update questions and change them. I answered your question. If you have a new issue post a new question.    If this answer helped you remember to accept it it will increase your reputation as well.

Answer (score 0):

As documented [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/handle-errors#resolve_a_401_error_invalid_credentials) the error 401 error: Invalid credentials is related to:

> ... the access token you're using is either expired or invalid. This error can also be caused by **missing authorization for the requested scopes** ...

If the token works with another type of request you may want to check the scopes.